# Task.Wait vs Task.RunSyncronously where task has call to WPF Dispatcher.Invoke

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I have a `Task` that I am starting and wish to wait for completion in a WPF app. Inside this task I invoke an `Action` on the dispatcher.

If I use `Task.Wait()` it appears to hang as if the method never finished. Also, breakpoints inside the Dispatcher.Invoke are never hit.

If I use `Task.RunSyncronously()` it appears to work correctly and breakpoints inside the Dispatcher are hit.

Why is there a difference?

Code sample below:

```
public void ExampleMethod()
{
    // When doing the following:
    var task = new Task(LoadStuff);

    // This never returns:
    task.Start();
    task.Wait();

    // This version, however, does:
    task.RunSyncronously();
}

private void LoadStuff()
{
    ObservableCollection<StuffObj> stuff = Stuff.Load(arg1, true);

    DispatchHelper.RunOnDispatcher(() =>
    {
        ...
    });
}

public static class DispatchHelper
{
    public static void RunOnDispatcher(Action action)
    {
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(action);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there's a major difference.  If you use `RunSyncronously` you just run the task in the UI thread.  If you start it up in a background thread and us `Wait` then the code is running in a background thread and the UI thread is blocked.  If the code within that task is invoking to the UI thread, and the UI thread is being blocked (by the `Wait`) then you've created a deadlock, and the application will remain frozen.

Note that if you used, `RunSyncronously` on that task from a non-UI thread, and the UI thread was being blocked by something else, you would still see the deadlock.

Now, as for what you should do, there are really two options here:

1. The task itself doesn't actually take a long time, and it really should run in the UI thread rather than in a background thread.  The UI thread won't be frozen (temporarily) for long enough to be a problem doing all of this work directly in the UI.  If this is the case, you probably shouldn't even make it a Task, just put the code in a method and call the method.
2. The task does take a long time to run, and then it updates the UI after doing that work.  If that is the case then it's important that it not be `RunSyncronously` but started in a background thread.  In order to prevent your entire application from deadlocking it will mean that you'll need to *not* block the UI thread through a `Wait` call.  What you need to do if you have some code that you want to run after the task finishes, is to add a continuation to the task.  In C# 4.0 this could be done by calling `ContinueWith` on the task, and adding in a delegate to be run.  In C# 5.0+ you could instead `await` on the relevant task (rather than `Wait`ing on it, which is actually a big difference) and it will automatically wire up the remainder of the method to run as a continuation for you (in effect it is syntactic sugar for an explicit `ContinueWith` call, but it's a very useful one).

Comment: Don't you mean .NET 4.5, there is no .NET 5 yet. Also, async methods generate a state machine rather than using ContinueWith.

Comment: @BrianReichle I meant C#, not .NET, but yes, it was wrong.  As far as `async`, yes it does generate a state machine, and that state machine adds itself as a continuation of the task being awaited.  The state machine is the mechanism whereby it knows how to pick up where it left off when the continuation runs, but the adding of a continuation to the task being awaited is how it runs *anything at all* when the `Task` finishes.

Comment: The state machine reschedules via the awaiter returned by `GetAwaiter()`, not `ContinueWith` (this allows us to await things other than tasks). They both call through to a common implementation, but `task.GetAwaiter().OnCompleted(...)` does not call `ContinueWith` (in particular, the former avoids creating a new task). But I suppose this is just getting pedantic, most people won't care about the implementation details :)

Comment: @BrianReichle Yes, I'm aware that it uses a different method, but the methods are semantically identical, so I saw no reason to distinguish between the two.